# Customize DatePicker/CalendarView

Tags: android

Is there a way to customize the [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) and/or [CalendarView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html) such that only specified fields appear. For e.g. in one instance, I'd like to see the `DatePicker` appear with only the month field showing, in another, I want it to appear with all but the year showing.

I've looked at creating custom controls, but that's really too much. I'm looking for a simple way to extend the existing controls.

Answer (score -1):

yes,

XML attribute..

```
<DatePicker android:calendarViewShown="false"/>
```

Using Java:

Let the `DatePicker` you created has id: `d1` so the code follows:

```
DatePicker selectDate =(DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.d1);
selectDate.setCalendarViewShown(false);
```

if you are creating `DatePicker` dynamically:

```
DatePicker selectDate = new DatePicker(this);
selectDate.setCalendarViewShown(false);
```

Comment: Can anyone please tell me why am I downvoted... I guess this is correct answer and it works.